# Change CSS class

Tags: jquery, css

How do I change CSS class on click in jQuery? I need change font color afer that.

```html
<a href="#">Click this to change color</a>
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried anything? This is more or less the "Hello world" of jQuery and the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/) contains a couple of examples. (found this link when searching for 'jquery click example')

Comment: Apply the color to `a:visited` pseudo-class. Once you visit a link,   the color would change. However if you are interested in jQuery, better to start from [JavaScript 101](http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/)

Answer (score 2):

First include jQuery in your project.

Than make a script that starts with the ready function. Basically this will wait for the execution before the page is loaded. This will be necessary because if you want to find an element, there has to be an element.

Than we will add the click function to the link. In that function we should first prevent the default so the link won't navigate.

Than add an class, so the color will change.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
})
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="link">Click this to change color</a>
```

Comment: same as Rafal Leśniak answer

Comment: But with an explanation and working snippet

Answer (score 0):

It is simply make it an CSS

```
a {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Comment: Technically, `a` represents all `<a>` elements, not necessarily the *unvisited* ones.

Comment: yes you are right. but using id selector like a#id {color: blue}. it will work

Answer (score -1):

You need this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $(this).addClass('color');
  });
})
```